# Data has been deleted from database but table row not removed and total record not reduced in php using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Data is Deleted database but table row not removed and total not reduced php ajax
I am creating an e-commerce site for my final year project. I am running into the problem with delete the product. if I delete product has been deleted from database success. but final total didn’t reduce and table row not removed what I tried so far I attached below along with screenshot image below.

**Table**

```
<div class="container">
                <table class="table table-striped" id="mytable">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ProductID</th>
                        <th>Productname</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Qty</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div style='text-align: right; margin:10px'>
            <label><h3>Total amount: </h3></label>
            <span style="font-size: 40px; color: #ff0911" id='total-amount'></span>
        </div>
```

**Display the Products**

```
<script> 
getProducts();
function getProducts() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'all_cart.php',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
            data.forEach(function(element) {
                var id = element.id;
                var product_name = element.product_name;
                var price = element.price;
                $('#mytable tbody').after
                (
                    '<tr> ' +
                    '<td>' + id + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + product_name + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + price + '</td>' +
                    "<input type='hidden' class='price' name='price' value='" + price + "'>" +
                    '<td>' + "<input type = 'text' class='qty' name='qty' value='1'/>" + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + "<input type = 'text' class='amount' id='amount' disabled/>" + '</td>' +

                    '<td>' +  " <Button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='deleteProduct(this," + id + ")' >Delete</Button> " + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>');
            });
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

**Calculating the Total**

```
$(function() {
    $(".price, .qty").on("keydown keyup click", function () {
        var price = $(this).parents('tr').find('.price');
        var qty= $(this).parents('tr').find('.qty');
        var sum = (
        Number($(price).val()) * Number($(qty).val())
        );
        $(this).parents('tr').find('.amount').val(sum);
        calculateAmount();
    });
});

function calculateAmount() {
    var total = 0;
    $('.amount').each(function(e){
        total += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $('#total-amount').text(total);
}
```

**delete product function**

```
function deleteProduct(event, id) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'remove.php',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data: {id: id},
                    success: function (data) {
                        $(event).parent('tr').remove();
                        calculateAmount();
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert(xhr.responseText);

                    }
                });
}
```

**remove.php**

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    include "db.php";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("delete from cart where id=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    if ($stmt->execute())
        {
            echo 1;
        }
    else 
        {
                echo 0;
        }
        $stmt->close();
        }
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of

    `$(event).parent('tr').remove();`
try

    `$(event).parent().parent().remove();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use logic like:

While displaying products (edit the line, **just assign dynamic id to tr tag**)-

```
....
'<tr id=tr_'+id+'> ' +
....
```

& in delete product function (remove relevant tr using id)-

```
....
$('#tr_'+id).remove();
....
```

In your code...

Diplay products function-

```
<script> 
getProducts();
function getProducts() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'all_cart.php',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
            data.forEach(function(element) {
                var id = element.id;
                var product_name = element.product_name;
                var price = element.price;
                $('#mytable tbody').after
                (
                    '<tr id=tr_'+id+'> ' +
                    '<td>' + id + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + product_name + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + price + '</td>' +
                    "<input type='hidden' class='price' name='price' value='" + price + "'>" +
                    '<td>' + "<input type = 'text' class='qty' name='qty' value='1'/>" + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + "<input type = 'text' class='amount' id='amount' disabled/>" + '</td>' +

                    '<td>' +  " <Button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='deleteProduct(this," + id + ")' >Delete</Button> " + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>');
            });
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

& in delete function-

```
function deleteProduct(event, id) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'remove.php',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data: {id: id},
                    success: function (data) {
                        //$(event).parent('tr').remove();
                        $('#tr_'+id).remove();
                        calculateAmount();
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert(xhr.responseText);

                    }
                });
}
```

I am just explaining the logic.. but you need to go in detail to adjust the remaining rhings.. :)

Comment: awesome Job sir thanks for the code best developer you are thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

if your removing data from table after delete try to use this code

1.after success return delete function run again `getProducts()` function data again fetch and reset in table

2.delete functionality return all data in success function using php go to `remove.php` and select all data query and return all data

```
function deleteProduct(event, id) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'remove.php',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {id: id},
                success: function (data) {
                     getProducts();
                    $(event).parent('tr').remove();
                    calculateAmount();
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);

                }
            });
```

Comment: if i call the  getProducts(); function data will be duplicated i attached screen shot image above sir. row not deleted and total not reduced